# Como ejecutar una funcion despues de un Loop del NgFor*

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, angular9

Me gustaria enviar una variable a una funcion despues de un primera vuelta (loop) del NgFor.

En el Html tengo esto:

```
<div *ngFor="let obj of objts; let i = index" class="col-md-3">
   {{obj.name}}
</div>
```

y en mi componente tengo esto:

```
catchName( petition ) {
    console.log( petition );
}
```

como puedo llamar la function CatchName y recoger el obj.name?

Muchisimas gracias quien pueda resolver esta duda!

Comment: hay una pregunta similar en inglés: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37087864/execute-a-function-when-ngfor-finished-in-angular-2

Answer (score 2):

simplemente es agregar una condicion dentro del ngFor, para que al momento en el que se cumpla la condicion basandonos en el index, en este caso despues de la primera vuelta, desplegara la funcion con el parametro del name que contiene dentro de ese ciclo en especifico.

```
<div *ngFor="let obj of objts; let i = index" class="col-md-3">
   {{obj.name}}
    <div *ngIf="i == 0">
        {{ this.catchName(obj.name) }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Si bien tu respuesta puede resolver lo solicitado, sería mejor acompañarla de una explicación que le indique a él y a cuantos la pueda ver, el porqué de la solución implementada. Quizá te ayude mirar [answer].

Comment: Muy cierto, gracias por la observacion.